# UITableView not showing images from URLs

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have this code that is supposed to show images from URLS. I think everything is good because when I print the count of images and `images` I get an array of 7 images.

Please look at my code and correct me where I did a mistake.

```
 import UIKit
 import SwiftyJSON
 import Haneke

 class  SlideViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate ,        UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview : UITableView!

 var images = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    getJSON()

}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return images.count
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

    let remote = images[indexPath.row]

    let imageurl = URL(string: remote)
    cell.images.sd_setImage(with: imageurl)


    return cell
}

func getJSON() {

    let url =  "http://localhost:8000/api/hello"
    let myuel = URL(string: url)
    let resquest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myuel!)

    resquest.httpMethod = "GET"


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resquest as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data,response,error in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(data)

        self.images = json["pic"].arrayObject! as! [String]
        print(self.images.count)
        print(self.images)


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }

    })
    task.resume()
     }


  }
```

Comment: It's better to use SDWebimage it takes the url and show the images .

Comment: Make sure the image url is not from the localhost since you are using localhost for api calling.

Comment: in the next view I'm using images from localhost and it's working !

Comment: @BhupatBheda check updated answer. it's not working

Comment: Please check your image url

Comment: @BhupatBheda can you show me where ? I checked the url in the browser and it's working

Comment: @leo0019 can you show the Json in your answer, so that community will help you properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to return a section from the following method and

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

use this extension to load and view images from url asynchronously

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
            })

        }).resume()
    }}
```

use above extension to load image to the imageView like this.

```
cell.imageview.imageFromServerURL(urlString: urlString)
```